# Wave diagram in QT (functionality issues in logic)

Tags: qt, c++11, qt4

Wave diagram in QT.. There was some functionality issues in logic. I tried a wave diagram logically using QPainter. Wave diagram is drawn perfectly but there was one line has drawn.. Any one help me to solve this problem.

//dialog.cpp

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include <QtMath>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QTGui>
#include <QtCore>


Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    e->accept();

    float scale = 40;
    //boolean negativeX = true;
    float width = 500;
    float height = 108;

    QPainter painter(this);

    QPen linepen(Qt::red);
    linepen.setWidth(2);
    QPoint p1;
    QPoint p2;

    painter.setPen(linepen);

    float xx, yy, dx=4, x0=width / 2, y0=height / 2;

    //float iMax = (width - x0) / dx;
    float iMax = 63;

    //float iMin = negativeX ? -x0 / dx : 0;
    float iMin = -63;

    for (int i=iMin;i<=iMax;i++) {
           float x = x0+xx;
           float y = y0-yy;
         p1.setX(x);
         p1.setY(y);

         xx = dx*i;
         float xscl = xx/scale;
         yy = scale * qCos( 3* xscl );

           x = x0+xx;
           y = y0-yy;

         p2.setX(x);
         p2.setY(y);

         painter.drawLine(p1, p2);

     }

   }
```

// dialog.h

```
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e);
```

// main.cpp

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
Dialog w;
w.show();
```

[image]

Comment: i tried that one, after initialization of xx and yy using p1.x and p1.y will get not working move to p1 concept.. so i used looping iteration of modified value of p1.x and p1.y

Comment: Please don't make massive wholesale changes to your question such that it invalidates answers. It defeats the entire purpose of SO. If you want to make those sort of changes, it should be a *new* question and you should ask it after you've understood answers to your current question. Have rolled back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not *sure* <sup>(a)</sup> if this is what's causing your problem since you have undefined behaviour (meaning *anything* could happen) but, the first time through the loop, you use `xx` and `yy` before they've been given a value:

```
float xx, yy, ...                 // will be arbitrary value.
float iMax = 63;
float iMin = -63;
for (int i=iMin;i<=iMax;i++) {
   float x = x0+xx;               // shouldn't be using them here.
   float y = y0-yy;

   p1.setX(x);
   p1.setY(y);

   xx = dx*i;                     // not set until here.
   float xscl = xx/scale;
   yy = scale * qCos( 3* xscl );
```

This *may* be a simple case of initialising them to zero before use, since that's likely to be the best offset for the initial point.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> It's certainly *feasible* that this is the case since the initial value of `xx` and `yy` may be such that it sets the initial point to the rightmost end of that straight line.

That means the initial line draw, far from being a small line forming part of the cosine wave, will be from that point to the leftmost point of that wave. You can check this by simply putting a `break` as the final statement within the `for` loop and seeing that the straight line is the only thing that appears.

You could *also* check it by actually debugging the code, either putting a breakpoint at the calculation of `x` and `y` and seeing what the `xx` and `yy` values are, or printing them out before each time you use them. Debugging skills are an invaluable tool in your arsenal.

If that is the case, setting `xx` and `yy` to zero before the loop starts should *definitely* fix your problem.

Comment: p1.x and p1.y is move concept of line drawing but i used after initialization looping of wave diagram will not worked. so i used before initialization.. But how to remove that straight line..

Comment: @Senthil, I've told you how to remove the straight line. I've now made it clearer in the addendum *why* it's happening. Please re-read the answer.

Comment: Thanks, i have initialized float x and y before the for loop. it will works fine..